# How to draw a box around something with the dimensions of something else?

Tags: rules, plain-tex

I'm using plain TeX and I've lifted a macro `\boxed` from the TeXbook (where it is called `\cstok` and slightly different) to put boxes around things in math mode:

```
\def\boxed#1{\hbox{\vrule\vtop{\vbox{\hrule\kern 1pt\hbox{$#1$}}
    \kern 1pt\hrule}\vrule}}
```

I use the macro like this to make boxed operators:

```
\def\bplus{\mathbin{\boxed+}}
\def\bminus{\mathbin{\boxed-}}
\def\btimes{\mathbin{\boxed\times}}
\def\bdiv{\mathbin{\boxed\div}}
```

I would also like to have a similar boxed `\circ`, but the obvious approach `\def\bcirc{\mathbin{\boxed\circ}}` results in an unpleasantly small box drawn around the `\circ`. Is there a general way to make the box as large as it would be with a `+` inside but with a both vertically and horizontally centered `\circ` instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I kept `\boxed` macro unchanged and added `\bboxed` macro, which respects the fixed frame dimension like around `+`. And `\mahthpalette` macro is added into definitions if you need to print index and index of index in the right size.

```
\def\boxed#1{\hbox{\vrule\vtop{\vbox{\hrule\kern 1pt\hbox{$#1$}}
    \kern 1pt\hrule}\vrule}}
\def\bboxed#1#2{\boxed{\ooalign{$#1\phantom{+}\vphantom{#2}$\cr
                                \hss$#1{#2}\vphantom{+}$\hss}}}

\def\bplus{\mathbin{\mathpalette\bboxed+}}
\def\bminus{\mathbin{\mathpalette\bboxed-}}
\def\btimes{\mathbin{\mathpalette\bboxed\times}}
\def\bdiv{\mathbin{\mathpalette\bboxed\div}}
\def\bcirc{\mathbin{\mathpalette\bboxed\circ}}
```

Comment: Try `\def\bsum{\mathop{\mathpalette\bboxed\sum}}` or `\def\bto{\mathrel{\mathpalette\bboxed\to}}`

Comment: OK, is corrected.

Comment: Almost. The `\bcirc` box is a little smaller than the other boxes..

Comment: @FUZxxl OK, corrected.

Comment: @egreg The width is correct. You are wrong.

Comment: @wipet OK, that's right. Shall we talk about building 52 math lists each time `\bplus` is called? Should we look at the time your macro needs compared to mine? More than six times slower. You surely know that each `\phantom` or `\vphantom` in math mode spawns a `\mathchoice`, don't you?

Comment: Of course, I know about 52 math lists. I only showed another approach to the given problem. And the implementation of the mathstyle-macro interaction by `\mathchoice` is one of few things which is IMHO implemented bad by Knuth. I know another approach to mathstyle-macro interaction, I wrote an experimental patch to TeX, but this is another story...

Comment: @egreg Knuth's answer in the [TUGboat](https://tug.org/TUGboat/tb35-1/tb109knut.pdf) regarding `\mathchoice` is kinda puzzling to me; first the earlier quote: "`\mathchoice` is somewhat expensive in terms of time and space, and you should use it only when you’re willing to pay the price." And his answer: "And well, I guess that quote implies my answer. For I was clearly willing to pay the price in 1982, so I’m certainly willing to pay zero today!". What does the "zero today" mean, either of you know?

Comment: @morbusg I still consider the decision of using `\over` for fractions the worst one made in writing TeX. "Zero today” may refer to the fact that computing resources are faster; however, the delay when `\mathchoice` is involved is still noticeable.

Comment: I still consider the decision of using `\over` as very good (because people can *write* document, not to *encode* a source for a computer). But I mean that `\mathchoice` internal implementation in TeX would be better without creating four independent math lists.

Answer (score 2):

You can also make the symbols to scale in subscripts and superscripts with `\mathpalette`. I add also a check for the dimensions, so the box will be at least as big as for the + sign.

```
\def\boxedopinner#1#2{%
  \vcenter{%
    \hbox{%
      \kern0.4pt\vrule
      \vtop{%
        \vbox{%
          \hrule
          \kern 1pt
          \setbox0=\hbox{$#1#2$}%
          \setbox2=\hbox{$#1+$}%
          \ifdim\wd0<\wd2 \dimen0=\wd2 \else\dimen0=\wd0 \fi
          \ifdim\ht0<\ht2 \ht0=\ht2\fi
          \ifdim\dp0<\dp2 \dp0=\dp2\fi
          \hbox to\dimen0{\hss\box0\hss}%
          \kern 1pt
          \hrule
        }%
      }%
      \vrule\kern0.4pt
    }%
  }%
}

\def\defineboxedsymbol#1#2#3{%
  \def#1{#2{\mathpalette\boxedopinner#3}}%
}

\defineboxedsymbol\bplus\mathbin+
\defineboxedsymbol\bminus\mathbin-
\defineboxedsymbol\btimes\mathbin\times
\defineboxedsymbol\bdiv\mathbin\div
\defineboxedsymbol\bcirc\mathbin\circ

$a \bplus b + c_{d\bplus e+f}$

$a\bcirc b$

$a\bminus b\btimes c\bdiv d$

\bye
```

[image]

Comment: This looks really great except for that the box seems to be a bit too long in the vertical dimension: The distances between the upper and lower sides of the box and the plus are noticably longer than the distances between the left and right sides. Thank you for your effort!

Comment: @FUZxxl That's a side effect of how the bounding boxes for the operation symbols are set. I'll try changing the top and bottom parts, but the result of `\bplus` is exactly the same as you had in your original code (except for the vertical shift down obtained with `\vcenter`). If you change the two `\kern 1pt` into `\kern 0.4pt` you get less vertical space.

Comment: Oh, I didn't realize that was the case. In this case, the original is probably faulty, too. Thank you for caring.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this.

```
\setbox0\hbox{+}

\def\boxed#1{\hbox{\vrule\vtop{\vbox{\hrule\kern 1pt\hbox to%  
\wd0{\hfil$#1\vphantom+$\hfil}}\kern 1pt\hrule}\vrule}}
```

`\hss` may be better than `\hfil` in the above def, but I'm not expert enough to be sure. This method really defines the width and a minimum height of the `boxed` macro, I'd possibly prefer to call this `opbox` instead of `boxed`.

Comment: Hm... This sounds like an interesting approach expect that it wastes a box register.

Comment: Also, it's not quite right. It works OK for the obvious operations. I did try setting the width of the box with a `hphantom` but the position of the `\circ` was messed up.

Comment: You can measure the width of the plus sign (it's 8.5pt, according to my log file for a 10pt Plain TeX doc) and set the width directly to avoid using a box register.